# assetResourcesForAsset: cause deadlock

Tags: ios, ios9, phasset, photokit

[image]

Two thread access fileName at the same time.

Set If 0 made deadlock. but If 1 was all going well.

So what brought this on?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not calling `+[PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:]` synchronously on the main thread. That method (and maybe other `PHAssetResource` methods, I haven't investigated yet) is executed on the main thread internally.

Comment: I also think so